# Use .htaccess to exclude subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, configuration

```
RewriteRule index.html http://localhost:5000/ [P]
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:5000/$1 [P]
```

above code work for example.com to point to localhost:5000 but my sub domain got effected too. I type in subdomain.example.com it run localhost:5000 too, how to exclude that?

Comment: Is it possible that the issue is outside .htaccess?  Do you have an /etc/hosts file or something similar (name depends on your operating system) that is pointing subdomains to the same location as the main domain?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the subdomain, just add the following rule bellow RewriteEngine directive

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: what does the second line do?